# Curved Label (non-linear) Transformation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, transformation, homography

I want to transform a curved, rectangular label on a bottle to the normalized form with OpenCV.

I know:

- the edge points of the label
- the contour as points of the label
- the template rectangle size and format

Example Image of mine:

[image: Example Picture of curved rectangle on bottle]

I have already found some similar topics, like transformation of a label of a jam or bottle. [jam example](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/how-to-flatten-the-image-of-a-label-on-a-food-jar) But this wasn't done in OpenCV. 
Example image of jam label:

[image: Example jam of src link 2]

How can I achieve a best transformed rectangular image out of the curved one? And / Or which functions to I have to use in OpenCV?

Additional Example Image for better demonstration:
[image: Another Example Image]

Comment: use getPerspectiveTransform() to get the transformation matrix then use perspectiveTransform().

Comment: The function takes 3 or 4 input points and maps them to the correct input model points. Unfortunately this is only working by linear transformation, where straight lines are really straight lines. In my example the rectangle consists of non-straight lines. Using these two functions would result in a rectangular warped region containing the curved rectangle like in the example above.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Hi did you find solutions? Thanks